# How to insert only one column from one table to a multi-columned table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have some trouble using INSERT into a table. Basically, I run my insert command and I get:

> Error Code 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during Query.

This is my insert command :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO t1(a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, e_id)
SELECT t1 a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, e_id FROM all_data;
```

For this problem I try increasing the connection time-out time.

However, after that I get:

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I have tried killing all possible processes. Without any success. Let alone the fact that if you increase the time-out time, then the killing process can take 30 times longer that the execution of the query.

I think my solution to this problem would be to try adding fewer data at a time. Hence, my question how to insert only one column into a multi-columned table?

**TL;DR:**

**Problem 1:** Insert command fails due to "Lost connection to MySQL server during Query"

**My solution:** Increase connection time-out time.

**Problem 2:** Insert command fails due to "Lock wait timeout exceeded".

**My solution:** Kill processes. After that attempt to add one column at a time.

**My final question:** How to insert only one column from another table to a multi-columned table ? e.g.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO t1(a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, e_id)
SELECT a_id FROM all_data;
```

Comment: Seem to have 2 problems here unless I'm misunderstanding. 1) Why the insert is deadlocking or timing out, and 2) how to insert only one value into a table with multiple columns.

Comment: `INSERT INTO t1(a_id) SELECT a_id FROM all_data;` but I think you've got a bigger problem to solve. I just can't imagine this is going to help though. Why are you timing out?

Comment: @JacobH You are right. However, I have used the same methodology for other tables, even with more columns that this one. I haven't been able to find out why I am deadlocking. Hence, I thought I should try this approach, which I don't know if it is doable.

Comment: @JNevill If I run this I get "Error 1364: Field 'b_id' doesn't have a default value". Is there a way around this ? If I add IGNORE will it help ?

Comment: `Ignore` just means ignore the error. The record causing the error will be discarded. That's probably not what you want. Is `b_id` set to NOT NULL? If that's the case then you will have to provide it a value or set a default in the table's definition. Again though, I think you are attempting to fix your actual problem (deadlocking/timeout) with a band-aid that probably won't serve your needs.

Comment: @Jnevill I see, it makes sense. I see in the definitions all columns are set to NOT NULL. So, I guess what I am asking is not really doable for this case. Would it make sense to provide some placeholder values?Would that be possible ?

Comment: You could totally just hard code something in there `INSERT INTO t1(a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, e_id) SELECT a_id, 0,0,0,0,0 FROM all_data;`  (I'm assuming those are all numeric/integer)

Answer (score 0):

> how to insert only one column into a multi-columned table?

It's likely that the long processing and lock wait timeout problems come from processing *too many rows* rather than *too many columns*.  Therefore, doing your insert job a column at a time won't solve your problem.

You need to process fewer rows at a time. It's hard to give you specific advice about that without knowing whether your `all_data` table has a primary key. But, here's an outline of the process assuming you have a primary key column called `primary_key_id`.

```
 SET @last_id := -1;

 INSERT IGNORE INTO t1( a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, e_id)
 SELECT a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, e_id 
   FROM all_data
  WHERE primary_key_id > @last_id
  ORDER BY primary_key_id
  LIMIT 1000

 SELECT MAX(primary_key_id) INTO @last_id 
   FROM all_data
  WHERE primary_key_id > @last_id
  ORDER BY primary_key_id
  LIMIT 1000
```

Then repeat the second and third queries until the second query inserts no rows.

I've set `1000` as the batch size. You might be able to use something larger or smaller.

If you can't use a primary key, you can consider breaking up your batches some other way. Maybe, for example, by first letter of name.  The first batch would be retrieved using `WHERE name LIKE '%A'`, the second by `WHERE name LIKE '%B'` and so on. You know your data, so you're the one to figure out how to break up your batches.

Comment: Thank you, this is very insightful. It had not occurred to me that I might need to reduce my rows rather than columns. However, all_data does not a have a primary key. Is there another way to go about this ?

Comment: The primary key is merely a convenient way to handle batches of data in your insert. You may be able to create batches using something like `a_id BETWEEN 0 AND 999`, then `a_id BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999`, etc.

Comment: Apologies, but I am not sure if I follow. Won't this only work if my id's are number to begin with ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this [isolation-level command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) before your insert, to tell MySQL not to wait if your all_data table is busy.

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```